# How to implement file coordination in UIDocument

Tags: ios, icloud, uidocument, nsfilecoordinator

I already implemented UIDocument functionality (`contentsForType:error:`, `SaveToURL:forSaveOperation:completionHandler:`, `loadFromContents:ofType:error:`) to store simple text files in iCloud.

How do I implement file coordination? What are the advantages? Do I need to perform changes on previous code for reading/writing operations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIDocument already provides file coordination "for free". See the UIDocument documentation here for further advantages of using UIDocument: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocument_Class/index.html

Comment: Can you help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613645/add-edit-in-exel-or-edit-photo-extension